# Question on proof of Abel's limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, power-series

Let be $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ a power series with $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$ , radius of convergence $0<R<\infty$ and assume that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kR^k$ exists.

Then, Abel's limit theorem states:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to R-}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kR^k$ (continuity from the left).

I have worked through the proof and got it so far - except that our professor begins with the simplification "without loss of generality we assume $R=1$". Due to this assumption all the subsequent manipulations become a lot easier. But why is he allowed to assume that?

Comment: Isn't it required that the $a_k$ be real?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I have added this to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can show this for a radius of $1$, then we can show
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
&=\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(a_kR^k\right)\frac{x^k}{R^k}\tag1\\
&=\lim_{u\to 1^-}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(a_kR^k\right)u^k\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(a_kR^k\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $1=\frac{R^k}{R^k}$
$(2)$: substitute $u=\frac xR$
$(3)$: apply the theorem for a radius of $1$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the theorem is true for $R=1$.  Now let $R>0$, and for $|x|<R$ write $x=Ry$, with $|y|<1$.

We have $\lim_{x\to R^-}\sum a_kx^k=\lim_{y\to1^-}\sum a_kR^ky^k=\sum a_kR^k$ because $a_kR^k$ is real and  $\sum a_kR^k$ converges.